# LRM Bug or Tool Bug?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use std.textio.all;

entity read_fail is
end entity read_fail;

architecture test of read_fail is
begin

  process
    variable l  : line;
    constant s  : string(2 to 5) := "1111";
    
    variable a  : std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);
    
  begin
    l := new string'(s);
    
    read(l, a);
    DEALLOCATE(l);
    
    report "done read";
    
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

and when run in ActiveHDL, I get the following error:

```
RUNTIME: Fatal Error: RUNTIME_0047 std_logic_1164-body.vhdl (1114): Index 1 out of range (2 to 5)
```

Now, I can see why this is happening, but I'm not sure if this is an LRM failure, or if Aldec have their own implementation? There is nothing (I can find) in the LRM that specifies that the line has to start from index 1.

If I change a to be a bit_vector, there is no problem (as I assume the string is aliased inside the read procedure, or 'range is used).

If there is an LRM/library issue, it would be nice to have it fixed in VHDL 2018/19.

### Edit

So this appears to be an Aldec issue, a work-around is to renumber returned slices:

```
procedure renumber (l : inout line) is
  variable tmp    : line;
begin
  tmp     := new string(1 to l'length);
  tmp.all := l.all;
  DEALLOCATE(l);
  l := tmp;
end procedure;
```

Comment: ModelSim 10.5 with VHDL-2008 enabled can compile and simulate the code.  I have previously reported numerous bugs to Aldec, in special related to advanced VHDL verification features like access types, so maybe they still have something to fix...

Comment: @MortenZilmer As have I. Mostly related to access types of unconstrained records. But they are usually quick to fix (and often provide a patch). Because this was in a standard library, thought it might be IEEE copyright code.

Comment: -2008 std_logic_1164-body.vhdl line 1114 is in procedure skip_whitespace, called from procedure read (line 1210, here `read(l, a);`).  skip_whitespace calls TEXTIO `procedure READ (L: inout LINE; VALUE: out CHARACTER; GOOD: out BOOLEAN)` which appears to be failing. The package body is implementation defined by ALDEC, outside the scope of the standardization effort.  From other occurrences this is an evaluation error (assignment involves subtype conversion). The designated object's designated subtype doesn't appear to be used here (5.4 Access type, 5.4.1 para 3).

Comment: The TEXTIO read for bit_vector (any type other than character or string, see 16.4 Package TEXTIO) performs it's own skipping, likely not using `procedure READ (L: inout LINE; VALUE: out CHARACTER; GOOD: out BOOLEAN)`. A treatise on why the code should work would take the lion's share of a maximum post size (30K) with all the quotes from the standard. (Works in ghdl, too.) Removing the index constraint from the constant s declaration would probably work in ALDEC.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks. Thought this was the case. This came from larger project where Im manually parsing a longer string and returning slices from it, hence the bounds not starting at 1 (as expected in Aldec's code). Ticket raised. Workaround for me is to renumber the returned slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the IEEE std_logic_1164 package body is not defined by Aldec but still distributed by IEEE. Please simply switch off the acceleration for this package in other simulators to get the same results as Aldec does.